# Validate SSL certificates with Microsoft.Owin

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, owin, servicepointmanager

I want to warn users about TLS connections with insecure certificates to a Microsoft.Owin self-hosted app similar to this (paraphrasing).

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

The ServerCertificateValidationCallback is never used in this situation, so this doesn't work:

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);
```

How is certificate validation done for connections to a Microsoft.Owin application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is used to validate "remote" certificate for things like `HttpClient`, but your app is an HTTP server itself.

Such an app picks up the server certificate from [Windows HTTP API](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background), which is usually controlled by the administrators of the machine and you shouldn't attempt to validate.

If your goal is to validate browsers/apps sending requests to your app, check the incoming request via [ApiController.Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834453(v=vs.118)) to see if it contains a client certificate.